# Net changes in network using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

## Background:

I have several products in a market and the customers tend to switch between these products. I need to calculate the net gain/loss of customers switching between two products such that the dynamics can be visualised in a visNetwork graph.

## Data:

A snippet of my dataset:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(value = c(2.5, 5, 20, 113, 25, 43.5, 25.5, 2.5, 
5, 22.5, 17.5, 32, 65, 7.5, 10, 45.5, 12.5, 10, 5, 37, 35, 20.5, 
10, 5, 7.5), source = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), 
    target = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
    2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 
    5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
"source", "target"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")

> head(df,10)
   value source target
1    2.5      A      B
2    5.0      A      C
3   20.0      B      A
4  113.0      B      C
5   25.0      B      D
6   43.5      B      E
7   25.5      B      F
8    2.5      B      G
9    5.0      C      A
10  22.5      C      B
```

Notice that not every product has to loss/gain customers.

## Problem:

In the above dataset Product A losses 2.5 customers to Product B and Product B losses 20 customers to Product A. Then Product A would have a net gain of 17.5 customers and Product B a net loss of 2.5 customers. I would like to make this calculation for all products using dplyr, since I make heavy use of dplyr in other parts of the analysis.

The resulting dataframe could have the following structure:

```
  from to value
1    B  A  17.5
```

Please disregard the fact that I have half customers :)

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: What part of my code are you interested in? I do not have much else than the above dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr :

```
mutate(data,new_value=apply(data,1,function(vec){ max(data[data$source==vec[3] & data$target==vec[2],"value"],0)})-value)
```

Using data table:

```
setDT(data)
data[,new_value:=apply(data,1,function(vec){ max(data[data$source==vec[3] & data$target==vec[2]]$value,0)})-value]
```

If you want to remove the previous values and have a final result:

```
mutate(data,value=apply(data,1,function(vec){ max(data[data$source==vec[3] & data$target==vec[2],"value"],0)})-value)[,c(3,2,1)]
```

Comment: Last suggestion is exactly what I am looking for - thank you! I will however need to spent some time to figure out why it exactly works :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. The way it works is the following: For every row it takes the source and target and takes the value from the row which has them in reverse: So first row S:"A" T:"B", it searches for the row with T:"A" and S:"B" and takes the value. I put the max( ,0) so in case the combination is not found it will return a 0 (for example S:"F" T:"B" does not exist) and afterwards I subtract the original value. I hope that was clear :)

Answer (score 0):

It will not make use of `dplyr`, but you could use `acast` to create a matrix and substract one triangle from the other

```
library("reshape2")

df.mat <- acast(df, source ~ target)
df.mat.u <- df.mat[upper.tri(df.mat)]
df.mat.l <- df.mat[lower.tri(df.mat)]

df.mat.l - df.mat.u
```

For this to work the matrix must be symmetric which it isn't in this case.

Using igraph you can get a symmetric matrix: [Reconstruct symmetric matrix from values in long-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095422/reconstruct-symmetric-matrix-from-values-in-long-form)